# How do I persist a parent config object across all instances of a child object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm new to OOP python and keep stumbling on this issue, here is my classes:

```py
class SFTP:
​
    """ Just a wrapper around pysftp module with extra functionality """
​
    def __init__(self,
                 host,
                 username,
                 password):
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        self.cnopts.hostkeys = None
        self.latest_file = None
        self.sftp_obj = pysftp.Connection(host=self.host,
                                          username=self.username,
                                          password=self.password,
                                          cnopts=self.cnopts)
​
    def _latest_file(self, remote_path, file_name) -> str:
        for server_file in self.sftp_obj.listdir_attr(remotepath=remote_path):
            if server_file.filename.startswith(file_name) and server_file.st_mtime > 0:
                return server_file.filename
​
    def to_df(self, remote_path, file_name, sep) -> pd.DataFrame:
        self.latest_file = self._latest_file(remote_path, file_name)
        if self.latest_file is not None:
            return pd.read_csv(self.sftp_obj.open(remote_path + self.latest_file), sep=sep)
​
​
class Inputs(SFTP):
    def __init__(self,
                 filename,
                 sep,
                 default_path,
                 backup_path):
        super().__init__(host=ENV_HOST,
                         username=ENV_USERNAME,
                         password=ENV_PASSWORD)
        self.filename = filename
        self.sep = sep
        self.default_path = default_path
​
    def _data(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        if self.filename == 'Report_1':
           data = self.to_df(remote_path=self.default_path, file_name=self.filename, sep=self.sep)
           return data
        elif self.filename == 'Report_2':
           data = self.to_df(remote_path=self.default_path, file_name=self.filename, sep=self.sep)
           return data
```

So here every time I'm calling `self.to_df` I will have a connection to the SFTP server and pulling the file, however, I will more than likely need all the files, so is there a way to pass in the `SFTP` obj and open 1 connection and use across all instances?

I realize that its this line in the constructor:

```
self.sftp_obj = pysftp.Connection(host=self.host,
                                  username=self.username,
                                  password=self.password,
                                  cnopts=self.cnopts)
```

Is this where I would use a class method? or maybe property annotation?

As at the moment I would have do use this `Input` class like this:

```
report1 = Inputs(filename='Report_1', sep='|', default_path='/PATH/TO/Report_1/')._data()
report2 = Inputs(filename='Report_2', sep='|', default_path='/PATH/TO/Report_2/')._data()
```

Each time opening a connection to the SFTP server...

Comment: Use composition / delegation instead of inheritance, and explicitely pass your `SFTP` instance to `Inputs` instances.

Comment: Can you show me with some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use composition / delegation instead of inheritance, and explicitely pass your SFTP instance to Inputs instances. Simplistic example of composition / delegation:

```
class Delegatee(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def do_this(self, arg):
        return (arg * self.arg1) + self.arg2


class Delegator(object):
    def __init__(self, arg, delegatee):
        self.arg = arg
        self.delegatee = delegatee

    def do_this(self, arg):
        return self.delegatee.do_this(self.arg + arg)


delegatee = Delegatee(1, 42)
delegator = Delegator(0, delegatee)
print(delegator.do_this(0))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, do I have to have the method of `do_this()` in both objects or is this merely an example of how you would change the state across the 2 objects?

Comment: I think you really need to _read_ about OO design principles - polymorphic dispatch (most important OO feature), composition / delegation, type inheritance (cf the [liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)) vs implementation inheritance, and how implementation inheritance is static form of composition/delegation. The very best text you'll find on those concepts (assuming some basic understanding) is the first part of [the GOF's "Design Patterns" book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/design-patterns-elements/0201633612/).

Comment: TL;DR : SO is not the place to write a complete book on OO design - specially when such books already exist ;-) - just beware: most introductory texts you'll find about OO are totally inept.

Comment: I got your example working for my code, and will begin a deeper study of OO design principles - thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome ;-) And really, get yourself a copy of the GOF - the design patterns catalog is not devoid of interest, but the most important part is what comes before.